# How can I convert a Spotfire dxp file from version 6 to an older version, i.e. 5.5?

Tags: spotfire

How can I convert a Spotfire dxp file from version 6 to an older version, i.e. 5.5 ?

Please let me know if I should clarify anything regarding this question.

Comment: In some situations it may not be possible as certain visualisations underwent considerable change (namely the TextArea and the MapChart). Could you elaborate on the complexity of your .dpx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotfire is *not* backwards compatible. The only thing you can do is rebuild it.

Added: To avoid confusion around forward / backwards compatible.
This means that you can open .dxp files saved with older versions of TIBCO Spotfire with newer versions, but you can not open files that are saved with a higher/newer version of Spotfire than that you are you are using.

See also this question: http://spotfirecommunity.tibco.com/community/forums/t/645.aspx

Comment: it's a dead link :) do you mean it's not backward compatible or not forward compatible? opening a 6.0 file with 5.5 is forward compatibility, e.g. 5.5 is compatible to files created with future versions (forward), backward compatibility means that 6.0 can open files created with 5.5. so 6.0 can't open files created with 5.5? or 5.5 can't open files created with 6.0? (I guess the forward / backward compatibility depends on whether you are looking from the file-to-software or software-to-file direction)

Comment: @EranMedan Files created in older versions can be opened in newer version, so yes from that perspective it is backward compatible :). Point is that files saved in newer versions can not be opened by older version. Will add that.